# How to avoid error when including multiple times

Tags: php

In this PHP script I am calling a model loader function multiple times. I would like the Master Model (parent of all models) to be included only once, but not included if I am not calling any models.

Also, the model loader will always be included. Thus, I do not want the Master Model be inluded if I'm not calling any models.

How can I achieve this?

script.php

```php
include("model-loader.php");

// Returns the models instances.
$Model1 = loadModel("Model1");
$Model2 = loadModel("Model2");
```

model-loader.php

```php
function loadModel($name) {
    include("MasterModel");
    return new $name();
}
```

Comment: You also need to be careful about including inside a function, is there a particular reason why you would want to do this as opposed to having the entire `loadMode()` function inside the include.

Comment: Note that `include` allows the included script to return to the calling script. This means you can `return new class() extends MakeModel {}` or whatever, then `return include 'MakeModel.php';` or whatever in your function.

Comment: Also, an autoloader and `use` statements will accomplish the same effect as desired (not "including" a file unless it's used somewhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`include` will include the file everytime it is called.

What you should use instead is `include_once`. It will include the script only once, even though you run the same function multiple times.

model-loader.php

```php
function loadModel($name) {
    // Will only be included once.
    include_once("MasterModel");
    return new $name();
}
```

You could also use `require_once`. Thus, `require_once` will rise a fatal error if the path leads to nothing. `include_once` will only rise a warning.